# How to insert data into multivalued field in SOLR?

Tags: solr

managed-schema

```
<field name="id" type="string" indexed="true" stored="true" required="true" multiValued="false" />
<field name="category" type="text_general" indexed="true" stored="true" multiValued="true"/>
```

data.csv

```
id  category
1   CA,USA
2   DW,USA
3   NY,USA
```

Feeding data as below:

```
curl "http://localhost:8983/solr/demo/update/csv?wt=json&separator=%09&f.category.split=true&f.category.seperator=%2C&f.category.encapsulator='&commit=true" --data-binary @data.csv -H 'Content-type:text/plain; charset=utf-8'
```

I mentioned the category field separator as %2c (encoded comma), but data is stored as:

```
category:["CA,USA"]
```

I am expecting the data to be stored as:

```
category:["CA","USA"]
```

Comment: Instead of the csv format, inserted data in json format and it worked.

    [
  {"id":"1","category":["this","is","category"]},
  {"id":"2","category":["this","is a new","category"]}

]
 and Then inserted as: 
    curl -X POST -H 'Content-Type: application/json' 'http://localhost:8983/solr/new_demo/update?versions=true' --data-binary @data.json

Answer (score 5):

The issue with your approach is a simple spelling mistake.

```
&f.category.seperator=%2C
```

It should be `&f.category.separator=%2C`.

I see you've solved it with JSON approach. But this one works just as well.

Answer (score 0):

I Thing there is issue with separator , because you are using file separator as separator=%09 and and also you are using same seperator foe multi valued  fields as f.category.seperator=%2C

Comment: Global fields are tab(%09) seperated and the category field is comma(%2C) separated. Am I missing something?

Comment: try using &escape=%5c .

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
curl http://localhost:8983/solr/update/csv?stream.file=exampledocs/books.csv&stream.contentType=text/plain;charset=utf-8
```

## NOTE: The full path, or a path relative to the CWD of the running solr server must be used.

[source](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/UpdateCSV)